# How is it spelled this sound?

Tags: interjections

I remember to have heard some interjection that sound like "Oops!" but without the /ps/ sound, just a short /u/ sound, but I'm not sure of whether it was what I really heard or how is it spelled. I think the speaker used it as apologetic, as if substituting the sentence "**I almost forgot...** such and such"

For example:

> Could you please move my car from the entrance?... I almost forgot, here are the keys.

Comment: There are infinite possible answers to this question, but there is nothing at all wrong with the the very idiomatic _"I almost forgot"_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I thought there was maybe a couple, that's why I asked, I've heard the one that sound like /ʊ/ or maybe /u/ and wanted some other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the interjection *oh!*, which, according to [one dictionary site](http://www.wordnik.com/words/oh), can mean:

> An exclamation expressing various emotions, according to the tone and manner, especially surprise, pain, sorrow, anxiety, or a wish; an expression of understanding, recognition, or realization.

So, there's is nothing wrong with saying:

> *Could you please move my car from the entrance?... Oh! I almost forgot, here are the keys*.

You might also use *ooh* (which rhymes with *do* or *shoe*), which, according to Google dictionary lookup, means:

> used to express a range of emotions including surprise, delight, or pain.

Finally, if you want to emphasize your own forgetfulness, you could use *d'oh!*, which is a [relative newcomer to the dictionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/d'oh). It has a pronunciation similar to *dough* but is usually uttered more emphatically, and it used to express:

> frustration or anger, especially at one’s own stupidity

It can be used humorously, which is how I'd interpret it if you said:

> *Could you please move my car from the entrance?... D'oh! Here are the keys*.

Comment: Yep, it was! there is an audio clip [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ooh#Interjection), and it's like what I recall I heard.

Comment: @rraallvv - I had the feeling that _ooh_ was what you were looking for. If it's any consolation, I wasn't even entirely sure how to spell it! It's something I say often but rarely use in writing.

Comment: @J.R. I'm glad that the OP is pleased, but I can't see "Ooh" or "oh" as apologetic. I'm not sure we have such an exclamation in English.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - You need to learn more about learners, I think. Sometimes you read too much into how a question is worded, and miss what the learner – with their incomplete grasp of the language – is actually trying to express.

Comment: @J.R. Well of course, there are thousands of things we all have yet to learn. I thought _apologetic_ was the main objective. You're right in thinking thst tt didn't occur to me that "apologetic" might not accurately express what he (wild guess on gender there) was seeking. The edited question is much clearer in concentrating on the _sound_.